# 6 player Dog variation

Tags: variants, dog

In [Dog](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2633/dog) there is a expansion from 4 to 6 players. The only variation I know and have played is 3 vs 3. Does anyone have experience with 2 vs 2 vs 2? Does that play well too?

Background: I'm thinking about doing a tournament and it would be easier to get the required number of boards if I could pit three teams against each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I talked with a friend who has experience playing Dog this way. According to him the game is much more competitive when played 2 vs 2 vs 2 instead of 3 vs 3. There are more enemy pieces underway and they have more opportunities to intercept yours.

I'm still looking forward to playing this variant myself one day, but at least the question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

Rule books on http://dogspiel.info or from board manufacturers leave it open. Popular software implementations like the [iPhone/iPad app Dog Board Game](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/dog-board-game/id458599976?l=en&mt=8) or the web-based BrettspielWelt.de use the 2 vs 2 vs 2 variant:

[image: Dog app on iPad, screen shot of 6-player card giving phase]

For the 3 vs 3 you have to define who receives a card from whom in the team: do you give a card to your team member on the right, on the left, or both?

I have played both variants, but I prefer the 2 vs 2 vs 2 variant and have played it more often. It gets particularly exciting when the two trailing teams start collaborating to prevent the leading team from finishing.